# Cannot find symbol in object array

Tags: java, arrays, oop

I'm trying to create an array of objects in Java. "Point" is a class with two constructors and makes objects which are subclasses of it.

```
Point[] name = Point[1]; 
    for(int i=0; i < name.length; i++) { 
        name[i] = new Point(a, 40, 5, "green");
    }
```

I have a "cannot find symbol" error pointing to the second time is says Point.

```
Launch.java:10: error: cannot find symbol
Point[] name = Point[1]; 
               ^
```

This code however generates no errors.

```
Point name = new Point(a, 40, 5, "green");
```

Can anyone help me pinpoint the cause of this error?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add the `new` keyword to initialize the array

```
Point[] name = new Point[1];
```

Comment: Thanks, I don't know how nobody spotted that. I'll accept the answer after the minimum time is up.